# Different Cost Price Attributes in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes

**Two different attributes: "Net cost price" and "Gross cost price"**

I tried to add a new attribute to Magento. I called it: "gross cost price". This is the price it costs me (*gross cost price*) when i buy it at a wholesaler excluding tax.

If I exceed a certain type of turnover the wholesaler gives me a discount based om the whosalers price ("gross cost price"). I call this the actual cost price (*net cost price*) excluding tax and i use the native product attribute "cost".

Problem: the new created attribute is shown in the backend (catalog) always **including** tax. The native attribute "Cost" is displayed excluding tax.

How can I display the new created whosalers price ("gross cost price") excluding tax in the backend (catalog) while keeping the other prices (i.e. MSRP, Special Price, Price) including tax and the native atribute "cost" excluding tax.

Thanks for your help!

Extra information:
The Attribute type: "Price" (See figure, Dutch)
[image: Creating Attribute in Magento]

Comment: What type of attribute did you use to create this new attribute?

Comment: Type: "Price". (Sorry for my late reaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem,  the price type attribute is processed in all conversions including currency and tax. This is why you are experiencing your issue. The stock Magento "cost" attribute is "text field". With integer validation for admin.   I had to create a tiered cost extension and I learned this one the hard way.  So create your attribute as similar to the stock cost attribute and that should solve your problem.